# Spring Webflow - Forms - maintaing form values between back/next

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have a spring webflow app which is a form wizard  - made up of 3 steps (each a seperate jsp).

I am using a form backing object to update the values of an object on pages 1 & 2 of my wizard.

At the end of step 2, the form is validated and processed on the server.

What I need to do, is maintain the form values a user has entered on each of the pages so that if they go back and forth (between submission) then the values are filled out.

Im not sure how to go about this - any help welcome.
Thanks

Comment: How are you going back and forth? Transitions or the browser back/forward buttons?

Answer (score 1):

If your model object(s) is in flow scope, its values will be maintained through transitions.